# xmlstarlet With multiple Namspaces

Tags: xmlstarlet

I am having requirement to extract the values from XML and update the elements values same on-demand. I am trying to use xmlstarlet utility to extract the value from XML, but it is not working for complex xml structure.

Used Commands :
cat server.xml | xml sel -N P=http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/processexec.xmi -N C="http://www.omg.org/XMI" -t -m "/P:process/P:Server/P:processDefinitions/P:jvmEntries/P:classpath" -v .

2 
      3   
      4   
      5   
      6   
      7     
      8       
      9     
     10     
     11     
     12     
     13       
     14     
     15     
     16

### 17

```
179     <components xmi:type="applicationserver.sipcontainer:SIPContainer" xmi:id="SIPContainer_1450084659639" name="" maxAppSessions="120000" maxMessageRate="5000" maxDispat        chQueueSize="3200" maxResponseTime="0" statAveragePeriod="1000" statUpdateRange="10000">
180       <stack xmi:id="Stack_1450084659639">
181         <timers xmi:id="Timers_1450084659639"/>
182       </stack>
183     </components>
184     <webserverPluginSettings xmi:id="WebserverPluginSettings_1450084659639" WaitForContinue="false" ConnectTimeout="60" MaxConnections="80" ExtendedHandshake="false" Serv        erIOTimeout="600"/>
185   </components>
186   <processDefinitions xmi:type="processexec:JavaProcessDef" xmi:id="JavaProcessDef_1450084659639" workingDirectory="${USER_INSTALL_ROOT}" executableTargetKind="JAVA_CLASS        " executableTarget="com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer">
187     <execution xmi:id="ProcessExecution_1450084659639" processPriority="20" runAsUser="" runAsGroup=""/>
188     <ioRedirect xmi:id="OutputRedirect_1450084659639" stdoutFilename="${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/native_stdout.log" stderrFilename="${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/native_stderr.log"/>
189     <monitoringPolicy xmi:id="MonitoringPolicy_1450084659639" maximumStartupAttempts="3" pingInterval="600" pingTimeout="300" autoRestart="false" nodeRestartState="STOPPE        D"/>
190     <jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1450084659639" verboseModeClass="false" verboseModeGarbageCollection="true" verboseModeJNI="false" initialHeapSize="3072" maxim        umHeapSize="3072" runHProf="false" hprofArguments="" debugMode="false" debugArgs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777" genericJvmArguments=        "-Demt.was.appname=LOBCProfile01 -Demt.was.debug=false -Demt.was.home=/upppasr1/ZIBEUAT2/was-bin/ZIBE/emt-was/855 -Demt.core.home=/upppasr1/ZIBEUAT2/was-bin/ZIBE/emt-was/        855 -Dcom.ibm.websphere.security.util.createBackup=false -Dcom.ibm.wsspi.security.crypto.customPasswordEncryptionClass=com.itic.emt.was.security.CustomEncryptionImpl -Dco        m.ibm.wsspi.security.crypto.customPasswordEncryptionEnabled=true -Demt.was.servername=APP_A1_KHBCG -Xmn512M -Xverify:none -Xgcpolicy:gencon -Xdisableexplicitgc -Xverboseg        clog:${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/native_stderr.log.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid,7,10000  -javaagent:/opt/appdyn/javaagent-ibm/4.2.1.8/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.controller.hostName=appdyn-        nam-gcg-test-2.nam.nsroot.net -Dappdynamics.controller.port=8181 -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=153583_GCB-LOBC-GM-HK_APAC_UAT -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=tcwgwm-LO        BCa09u_null_APP_A1_KHBCG -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=LOBC_HK_WAS -Dappdynamics.agent.logs.dir=/upppwsr1/ZIBEUAT2/was-apps/ZIBE/ZIBE_Runtime/profiles/ZIBECell/LOBCProfile        01/logs/APP_A1_KHBCG -Dappdynamics.controller.ssl.enabled=true -Dappdynamics.force.default.ssl.certificate.validation=true -Dappdynamics.agent.accountName=customer1 -Dapp        dynamics.agent.accountAccessKey=ef0334ff-7c79-4f78-a7eb-7d2fa4e0a325 -Dappdynamics.agent.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2" executableJarFileName="" disableJIT="false">
191       <classpath>/anc/sdfd/jab.jar:[]</classpath>
192       <systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1450084659646" name="com.ibm.security.jgss.debug" value="off" required="false"/>
193       <systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1450084659647" name="com.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug" value="off" required="false"/>
194       <systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1450697072560" name="HttpSessionReaperPollInterval" value="30" required="false"/>
195       <systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1450697072628" name="config_consistency_check" value="false" required="false"/>
196       <systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1450697072647" name="javax.net.debug" value="false" required="false"/>
197        <systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1465366047008" name="com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine" value="true" required="false"/>
198     </jvmEntries>
199   </processDefinitions>
200 </process:Server>
```

Comment: Your commands look to be a bit strangely formatted, if you reformat them it will be helpful to anyone reading your question

Answer (score 0):

Seems your given xml  is not full.  But, I understood clearly, you were trying to parse websphere appserver server.xml.  It can be achieved easily.
Have attached the script  for your understanding. Hope it will address your requirement.

echo "JVM Entries"
cat server.xml | xmlstarlet sel  -t   \
-m "/process:Server/processDefinitions/jvmEntries"  -v "concat('InitialHeapSize:',@initialHeapSize,' MaximumHeapSize:',@maximumHeapSize)"  -n \
-m "/process:Server/processDefinitions/jvmEntries/@verboseModeGarbageCollection" -v "concat('verboseModeGarbageCollection',@verboseModeGarbageCollection)" -n \
-m "/process:Server/processDefinitions/jvmEntries/@genericJvmArguments" -v "concat('GenericJvmArguments:',.)" -n \
-m "/process:Server/processDefinitions/jvmEntries/systemProperties" -v "concat('JvmPropertyName:',@name,' Value:',@value)" -n 
echo "ThreadPools"
cat server.xml | xmlstarlet sel  -t -m "/process:Server/services/threadPools" -v "concat('ThreadPoolName:',@name,'*~','minimumSize :',@minimumSize,'*~','maximumSize:',@maximumSize,'*~','inactivityTimeout:',@inactivityTimeout)" -n

xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/process:Server/services/threadPools[@name='WebContainer']"  -v "concat('ThreadPoolName:',@name,'*~','minimumSize :',@minimumSize,'*~','maximumSize:',@maximumSize,'*~','inactivityTimeout:',@inactivityTimeout)" server.xml